# Python reports a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python

Error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'.

I tried to fix it but it doesn't work.

```py
def show_homework_list(link, page, session, header) -> None:
    hw_response = session.get(link, headers=header).text
    hw_soup = BeautifulSoup(hw_response, "lxml")
    hw_content = hw_soup.find("div", id="content")
    hw_table = hw_soup.find("table", class_="grid gridLines vam hmw")
    hw_info = hw_table.find_all("tr")

    os.system("cls")

    for i in range(1, len(hw_info)):
        lg = hw_info[i].find("td", class_="light").text.strip()
        br = hw_info[i].find("td", class_="breakword").text.strip()
        nw = hw_info[i].find("td", class_="nowrap").text.strip()
        text = f"\n{i}) {lg} | {nw.split('\n')[0]}\n{br}\n"
        print(text)
        print("-" * 40)

    print(f"\n<--  {page}  -->\n")
```

Comment: `hw_soup.find("table", ...)` returns nothing so `hw_table` is `None`. You have to check `hw_table` before `hw_table.find_all("tr")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML response does not contain a tag `table` with classes `grid`, `gridLines`, `vam` and `hmw`. If so then your code will work.

Suppose the following HTML content:

```
hw_response = '''\
<div id="content">
    <table class="grid gridLines vam hmw">
        <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
        <tr><td>World</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
'''
```

```
hw_soup = BeautifulSoup(hw_response, "lxml")
hw_content = hw_soup.find("div", id="content")
hw_table = hw_soup.find("table", class_="grid gridLines vam hmw")
hw_info = hw_table.find_all("tr")
```

Output:

```
>>> hw_info
[<tr><td>Hello</td></tr>,
 <tr><td>World</td></tr>]
```